# Javascript function to bring current day of the week info not working

Tags: javascript, date

I created this function long time ago which it was displaying the information required to the web page for the current day of the week.

I have not changed the code since then, but it is now displaying the previous day's information (e.g. on Thursday it shows Wednesday's information).

I was hoping that someone could help me figure out what's wrong with the function below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay();
    $(".menu").hide();

    if (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek <= 5 )
        $("#menu" + dayOfWeek).show();
    else
        $("#menu1").show();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**
The function is supposed to bring information from Monday to Friday.
On JSFiddle it works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/4rm4swuf/) but on the home page of the webpage it does not seem to bring the correct date.
It migh be an issue with the feed?
However there is another page on the website which uses a similar function and it works ok. 
On this page is not bringing "Jueves"/Thursday 
http://latabladegongora.com/index.php

On this page is showing "Jueves"/ Thurday.
http://latabladegongora.com/menu.php

Which indicate that the data should be ok.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post  the JSfiddle?

Comment: Did youve check your OS time? ...

Comment: Is strange, on JSfiddle works OK, but on the page is bringing the previous day.

Comment: @Jonasw , I´ll check on the server, as I´ve been recently migrated to a dedicated server.

Comment: Unless you can post code here that displays the issue, this is off topic as it isn't a javascript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's [Date#getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method returns the index of the current day (0-6), where Sunday is day 0 and Saturday is day 6.

```js
console.log(['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'][new Date().getDay()]);
```

Pay careful attention to this note from the spec (emphasis mine):

> **Return value** 
>   An integer number corresponding to the day of the week for the given date, **according to local time**: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

The date it returns will match the current date from your browser. You can try logging `new Date()` to verify what it thinks the date is.

Comment: This doesn't say why the OP has their issue, nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This function seems to be working fine for me and returns the correct day of the week. (i.e. console log in your function returns 4 for today, which is a Thursday). Maybe make sure your operating system time is correct?

Comment: Thank you, Ive checked on JS fiddle and can see that it works fine too, I really dont know what is happening.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a error(contradiction) in the logic

```
    if  (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek <= 5 )
        // possible values of dayOfWeek are: 1,2,3,4,5
        $("#menu"+dayOfWeek).show();
        // result can also be $("menu1") ...as bellow in the else statement
    else
        $("#menu1").show();
```